# Pythonic handling of this error case

Tags: python, error-handling, assert

In the code below, is my use of `assert` justified? If anything is wrong, an error will occur anyway when I try to access the attributes. On the other hand, the assert provides a descriptive error message.

Do you think I should keep the assertion?

```
class WeakBoundMethod:
    def __init__(self, meth):
        assert (hasattr(meth, '__func__') and hasattr(meth, '__self__')),\
               'Object is not a bound method.'

        self._self = weakref.ref(meth.__self__)
        self._func = meth.__func__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the `assert` here is checking an assumption the code is making. It will fail if the class is used incorrectly (i.e. programming error).

If this is indeed the case, then the use of `assert` here is IMHO justified. True, Python generously throws exceptions when things are used incorrectly, and EAFP is a good strategy. Yet, sometimes the errors thrown by the interpreter aren't descriptive enough to make it easy to locate the problem, and an `assert` in such cases is appropriate. It should also be coupled with appropriate documentation that states how the class expects to be used (i.e. the passed method should have certain attributes).

---

If I have misunderstood your sample and you're using the `assert` here to validate something the *user* could err with, then it's not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, that's how I use the code. I also wrote the documentation. The entire class can be found here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4574

Comment: @Paul: [disclaimer] without careful reading of the whole class, I think the `assert` there is fine

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain what you don't agree with. Since this question calls for some judgement and opinion/personal preferences, I think it's interesting to discuss.

Answer (score 4):

`assert` is *not* for input validation, it's for finding flaws in the assumptions *you* built your code on. It's a debugging and documentation tool, but it can be disabled. If you want to provide a good error message, `raise TypeError("Object is not a bound method")` - that's what it's for.

Comment: But I don't use it for input validation here. I'm checking an error condition that can only ever occur because of the programmer. Or did I get assertions wrong?

Comment: @Paul: Methods arguments **are** input. Not *user* input, but still input in that it comes from a source that isn't always trusted to provide data that's usable, and therefore needs to be validated. Plus, a `TypeError` is much more descriptive for the programmer.

Comment: But still, it's the kind of input that can only be wrong if the programmer makes a mistake, it cannot come from the users. Isn't that what assertions are for?

Comment: I don't think so (it is, of course, arguable). As Wikipedia states, "[A]n assertion is a predicate [...] placed in a program to indicate that the developer thinks that the predicate is always true at that place," and I'd say it's useful to limit assertion failures to signify errors in the code they belong to, not in its use. Also, look at the standard library - `TypeError`, `RuntimeError`, `NameError`, `UnboundLocalError`, etc. are used for errors that can only be caused by errors in "userland" code or sloppy programming. I don't think a single stdlib function raises `AssertionError`.

Comment: +1  if you can think up a situation where the assert would fail .. it probably shouldn't be an assert.  asserts are just comments which pack a punch!